# Inverse weighted average cost

Tags: inverse, average, inverse-function

I have calculated a weighted average cost for a new goods of a specific product as following:

`inQuantity` [received quantity of that product] = 100

`inCost`     [the cost of received goods of that product] = 10

`currentQuantity` [the quantity in stock of that product] = 50

`currentCost`     [current cost for that product] = 5

`totalQuantity`   [received quantity + current quantity in stock] = in quantity + current quantity

`weightedAverage` = $$\frac {\text ({inQuantity} \times \text{ inCost}) + \text ({currentQuantity}\times \text { currentCost})} {\text {totalQuantity}}$$

So; the new `currentCost` will be = 8.3 while I don't have a reference for the old `currentCost` which was (5).

Now I want to return those goods back, and I want to reverse this calculation, so; the `currentCost` should return back to (Whatever it was before calculation [ex: 5]).

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your definition of the weighted average...please check to make sure I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: Note 2:  I don't understand your question.  Nothing you wrote appears to depend on a variable called "original cost".  What variables am I allowed to change?  What result am I after?

Comment: @lulu, I have updated my question.

Comment: I don't understand what your edit clarifies...all you did was to undo some of my formatting changes."original cost" is still undefined and there is still no clear question.  (you tell us you don't know the original cost and then you tell us it is $5$, for example).

Comment: @lulu, Original Cost is the Current Cost before calculating the weighted average.

Comment: Using "OriginalCost" and "CurrentCost" to mean the same thing is confusing.  But, still.  What is the question?  Obviously If I know every term in your formula except for one, I can calculate the missing one.  Is that all you are asking?

Comment: To be precise:  CurrentCost = (NewCost $\times $ TotalQuantity-InQuantity $\times $ InCost)/CurrentQuantity.  But I doubt this is what you are asking.

Comment: @lulu, the currentCost is the cost before calculating the weighted average = (5). And after calculating the weighted average, the currentCost became = (8.3). I want to reverse the calculation back to return to the original currentCost, which was = (5). hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Do you mean $8.3$ for the newCost?  Where did $3.8$ come from? Does the formula I wrote in my prior comment settle the matter?  If no, why not?  The only problem here is the lack of clarity.  The formula is very simple...if you just state what values you know and which you seek, it should be easy to solve.

Comment: Sorry, it's (8.3).

Comment: @CairoCoder Beyond the current topic: I´m grown up in Cairo. I had a good time in Cairo. Now live in Germany. With lulu you are in best hands as the previous comment show. You have to be clear with the definitions of inQuantity ,inCost  and currentCost (original Cost). It would be helpful if you add the **definitions** to your question. Only then it is possible to help you.

Comment: @lulu, Afrer calculating the weighted average, and using you formula: CurrentCost = (8.3*(150-100)*10)/150) which is not equal to original cost (5)

Comment: @callculus, glad to hear that my friend. I will do that of course. thanks :)

Comment: Keep in mind that your NewCost isn't really $8.3$, you rounded that.  It is $8.\overline 3=8+\frac 13$.  With that correction, I do indeed get $5$ out of my formula.

Comment: Just to be clear on the order of operations:  my proposed formula is $$\text {OldCost}=\frac {\left(\text {NewCost}\times \text {TotalQuantity}\right)-\left(\text {InQuantity}\times \text {InCost}\right)}{\text {CurrentQuantity}}$$

Comment: @lulu, could you please write it in numbers, so; I can figure out your point.

Comment: I have also updated my question with more clarifications.

Comment: $$\frac {(8.\overline 3\times 150)-(100\times 10)}{50}=\frac {1250-1000}{50}=5$$

Comment: @lulu, You made my day, thanks a lot :)